# 301 Redirect Rule

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

Need help with an 301 htaccess redirect rule doing the following:

www.name.com/wordA/wordB/*    to    www.name.com/WordNEW/wordA/wordB/*

we are basically adding "WordNew".

I have three wordA and five wordB for a total of 15 path variations.

Answer (score 1):

Spin this on for size:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/WordNEW [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /WordNEW/$1 [L,R=301]
```

#### Broken down

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/WordNEW [NC]
```

Check the requested URI does not start (`!^`) with the same folder path (`/WordNEW`) as the final. If it does, you've already redirected once or you are already there. If you don't check then you can end up on a loop rewriting the path over and over again.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /WordNEW/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If it passes, grab the whole requested URI (`^(.*)$`) and prepend with the new folder path (`/WordNEW/$1`).  Then flag this as the last rule (`L`) in the [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) while redirecting under 301 (`R=301`).

Answer (score 0):

if WordNEW is in a constant position my quick and dirty solution would be to split the url string on '/'.  at index 1  I would prepend the string WordNEW/ .  For a more feasible solution I will need a few moments to think.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a simpler rule:

```
RewriteRule !^WordNEW/ /WordNEW%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```